# Passing CLI args to `--sup`-generated application

Tags: elixir

I'm experimenting with `--sup`-generated applications, how they are
started and how to pass CLI arguments.

I generate the application with `mix new --module MyApp --sup
myapp`. Before compiling `lib/myapp/application.ex` is modified to become

```
defmodule MyApp.Application do
  @moduledoc false
  use Application
  require Logger

  def start(type, args) do
    Logger.debug("[#{inspect self()}]:MyApp.Application.start(type=#{inspect type}, args=#{inspect args})")
    children = []
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyApp.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

Mainly the log line is added so that one can see what is passed
around.

Running the program with `iex -S mix` mainly gives the following output:

```
06:55:18.562 [debug] [#PID<0.111.0>]:MyApp.Application.start(type=:normal, args=[])
```

To validate that the `args` received by `start` are coming from
`mix.exs`, I modified the `application` function in with `mod:
{MyApp.Application, [1, :two]}`. Execution yields:

```
07:05:41.629 [debug] [#PID<0.143.0>]:MyApp.Application.start(type=:normal, args=[1, :two])
```

as expected.

**My first question is**: the type of the application (the first
argument to `start` callback) is reported as `:normal` while the
documentation for the `Application` behavior defines only three types
`:permanent`, `:transient` and `:temporary`. What do I miss here?

**The second question is**: how to make a self contained executable
and dispatch the arguments from the command line.

Self contained executable are created with `escript`, right? I add
the line `escript: [main_module: MyApp]` to the `project` function in
`mix.exs` and added a `main(args)` function to `MyApp` module:

```
defmodule MyApp do
  require Logger

  def main(args) do
    Logger.debug("[#{inspect self()}]:MyApp.main(args=#{inspect(args)}")
  end
end
```

Execution of `mix escript.build && ./myapp a b` produces two lines of log:

```
07:53:22.973 [debug] [#PID<0.77.0>]:MyApp.Application.start(type=:normal, args=[1, :two])
07:53:22.980 [debug] [#PID<0.79.0>]:MyApp.main(args=["a", "b"]
```

`MyApp.Application` (and the supervision tree if I had implemented
one) is started with the parameters provided in `mix.exs` and the
`main` function is called with the command line arguments. Besides,
both run in different processes... So how to pass the cli arguments to
the supervision tree?

I was thinking about commenting out the line `mod: {MyApp.Application,
[1, :two]}` in `mix.esx` and modify `MyApp.main()` to call `MyApp.Application.start()`:

```
defmodule MyApp do
  require Logger
  require MyApp.Application

  def main(args) do
    Logger.debug("[#{inspect self()}]:MyApp.main(args=#{inspect(args)}")
    MyApp.Application.start(:normal, args)
  end
end
```

which execution produces:

```
08:08:16.865 [debug] [#PID<0.76.0>]:MyApp.main(args=["a", "b"]
08:08:16.868 [debug] [#PID<0.76.0>]:MyApp.Application.start(type=:normal, args=["a", "b"])
```

This seems good but I'm wondering if this is the right way, especially
if there is some kind of magic the runtime does before calling
`MyApp.Application.start` that might be not executed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, usually the `type` `:normal` is passed to start the main Supervision tree unless you're building a distributed system. You normally pass other types `:permanent`, `:transient`  or `:temporary` to start specific apps. [Elixir](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#module-application-module-callback) and [Erlang](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html) docs.

For the second question, you can start the Supervision tree manually through a `start_link/2` and pass the `args` to that function, there's no "magic" by either starting the `Application` manually or through the `mix.exs` (Better than manually). Only thing is that your `Application` callback shouldn't do any code operations and only start Supervisors, etc...